# How to send subsequent event notification from a google calender to guest user without sending invitation?

Tags: .net, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google Calendar API to notify guest user from my own Google calender. I am adding events to my calendar with some guest user. But every time I make an event to that calendar with guest user, guest user have to accept invitation to get notification from that event. Is this possible to make a way so that a specific guest user need to accept invitation for the first time and then he don't need to get further invitation from that calendar??

For example: 
I have a calendar in my Google Calendar account named "FriendCollaboration". I may need to create 5 events today with two guest user. But I need to send them invitation maximum one time. When they accept that invitation they don't need to get further invitation from that calendar.

I am using latest Google Calendar Api.v3 with .net client. Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

By default and by design, a user needs to manually accept all events for their primary calendar allowing them to confirm availability.

For secondary calendars, users can [configure the calendar to auto-accept events that don't conflict with another event for time](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/34584?ctx=tltp&hl=en).

Comment: I have seen your reference and I know this is possible via changing setting in my Google calendar. But I was asked how to do that using api. I want to do something like that in my web application. But I couldn't find any way to do that using Google Calendar API.